# Question's body is too big

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My proposal may apply for others communities, but it's mainly for Stack Overflow. Look at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258776/nested-collection-fields-in-sonata-admin). I do not doubt that could be a good question, but the simple fact of being so extensive makes me uncomfortable reading it, and certainly there are some more extensive than that.

It is obvious that sometimes you need a lot of code or images for explaining yourself, but it would be nice to minimize the impact to the reader. It wouldn't be so difficult to make the code hidden with some expansible components instead of the actual scrollable, and maybe for big images showing on mouse click only. These are some ideas, but any ideas that contribute to compacting big questions are welcome, too.

Comment: I'm not sure that question actually needs *any* image. Or should have that much code. Remember, there's "minimal" in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a reason.

Comment: "Look at questions like this one [link to bad question with huge amount of bloat]": I'm not entirely convinced.

Comment: While the question does have some bloat, it came as a result of requests for more information. It even has a bounty which relates to an understanding that the question is rather involved. This question is not exactly the poster child for bloat questions, nor wall of text, nor code dump - as it is grouped, explained, and has been attentive to other user's requests for more information.

Comment: That was just an example, the point is not the quality. The fact is that sometime the code and images are needed and extend the question, and maybe can be improved, visually at least.

Comment: Even for bad questions

Comment: I'd argue that if a question is uncomfortable to read, you don't need to hide sections of it, you'd need to refactor the question. If you have actually good counter examples, please provide them.

Comment: @Bart I hope that the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-in-symfony-2-x be enough for you.

Comment: Don't misuse them, but StackSnippets have an option to show/hide code.

Comment: Whether that question has any value for *future* users is, of course, debatable.

Comment: @abdiel... your title is question body.... link to a question,  not an answer. And if you cant find good, on topic questions that are that long, then no it's not a problem. We shouldn't put up a feature to make terrible questions smaller.... they should (and most likely will) disappear

Answer (score 5):

No, this is a terrible idea. Expandable components suck. Unless you have limited screen real-estate, they are a solution in search of a problem. That's not the case in a web browser: all content is scrollable. If you want to skim past something quickly, use the scroll bar. I'm going to have to use the scroll bar anyway, probably through the little spinny wheel attached to my mouse. Why should I *also* have to fiddle with clicking on some expando-box?

If there is something so ugly and irrelevant that you would want to collapse it out of view, it probably shouldn't be there in the first place. The site is collaboratively edited for a reason. Don't make others suffer just because you had to.

Besides, being able to "collapse" a section of a question (or worse, having it automatically collapsed) just increases the likelihood that it'll get ignored when someone tries to answer it. We already have a good way to ignore questions: the back button.